# Sphinx: Write footnotes in place, display at end

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'd like to be able to author footnotes at the point where they are referenced, but then only have them display at the end of the document, where `.. rubric: Footnotes` appears.

Like this:

```
Lorem Ipsum[#lorem]_ dolor sit blah blah.

.. [#lorem]

   The footnote text here.

The next paragraph. Salve regina mater misericordiae, vita dulcedo.

.. rubric: Footnotes
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

Lorem Ipsum^1 dolor sit blah blah.

The next paragraph. Salve regina mater misericordiae, vita dulcedo.

Footnotes:
 1 The footnote text here.

---

According to [the docutils docs](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#footnotes) this should be possible:

> Footnotes may occur anywhere in the document, not only at the end.
>   Where and how they appear in the processed output depends on the
>   processing system.

But I can't find how to make the processing system (Sphinx, using the built-in `make html`) put them only at the bottom, instead of wherever they appear.

Comment: A solution that works for citations (which otherwise work the same, but have text labels) would be especially helpful.

Comment: i've opened an issue mentioning the idea: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3974

Answer (score 0):

I've used the footnote approach, however, you must be careful about where you're placing the refs. So, my `modules.rst` look like this:

```
Brief
-----

.. automodule:: modules
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:


Sub modules
-----------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   modules.ahp
   modules.grid

Plot module
-------------------

.. automodule:: modules.Plot
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

Score module
-------------------

.. automodule:: modules.Score
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

Skillset module
-------------------

.. automodule:: modules.Skillset
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

util module
-------------------

.. automodule:: modules.util
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

|hr|

.. rubric:: Footnotes

.. [#euclidian] `Wikipedia <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition>`_
```

Since that my `utils` module contains the function where I'm using the footnote, it works like the expected. (It just creates a reference to a div in the current page)